# Jetty Proxy Servlet : Handle Redirection

Tags: proxy, jetty, embedded-jetty, http-proxy

If the response from server is a redirection i.e. a 302 status with location header , Jetty's ProxyServlet does not handle that and the control redirects to original server . How can i resolve this ? Also how can i change the Response and Response headers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override a method in `ProxyServlet` that lets you rewrite headers. So you can, for example, see if there is a `Location` header, and if so remove the target URL and replace it with the URL that the client requested. This is how I did it:

```java
@Override
protected String filterServerResponseHeader(HttpServletRequest clientRequest, Response serverResponse, String headerName, String headerValue) {
    if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("location")) {
        URI targetUri = serverResponse.getRequest().getURI();
        String toReplace = targetUri.getScheme() + "://" + targetUri.getAuthority();
        if (headerValue.startsWith(toReplace)) {
            headerValue = clientRequest.getScheme() + "://" + clientRequest.getHeader("host")
                + headerValue.substring(toReplace.length());
            log.info("Rewrote location header to " + headerValue);
            return headerValue;
        }
    }
    return super.filterServerResponseHeader(clientRequest, serverResponse, headerName, headerValue);
}
```